# Calculate area under curve from x,y dataset without even x-step in python

Tags: python, area, auc

I have a dataset from some CO2 concentration (ppm) values over time, and I would like to know the area under the curve between some time-points.

The most straight-forward solution would be to integrate the function between those time-points, however, I don't know the function, only the values.

Is there any way to integrate the data over a certain period of time directly in python? (without knowing the function) e.g., to calculate the area under the curve between lets say hour 2 and 3 in order to know the amount of CO2 during that period of time

[image]

Comment: Coult you post an example of your data? Also, do you want to calculate the area under the curve in order to get the relative frequency of observations between two dates?

Comment: I posted the data, what I want is to calculate the area under the curve between lets say hour 2 and 3 in order to know the amount of CO2 during that period of time

Answer (score 1):

There is various ways of integrating functions, given only fixed samples. The simplest is probably using the trapezoidal rule. Using numpy, you can do this as follows:

```
import numpy as np
result = np.trapz([1,2,3], x=[4,6,8])
# result = 8.0
```

You can find more examples here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.trapezoid.html#scipy.integrate.trapezoid